# Powershell Open File, Edit File, Update File - document lock issue

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with a list of multiple files that exceeded x characters.  What I am trying to do is open each file, scan each line of the file, and if a file is more than x characters long I move the line to the next line so the file does not exceed x characters.  That piece works great.  The problem I am having is updating the text file I am trying to change/edit.  I suspect the lock is the powershell script since the script is reading the file.  Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do to update the original text file or remove the lock? Thanks for any help! My code is below:

```
[int] $limit = 131
$path = get-content C:\document\fix.txt
foreach ($f in $path)
{
Get-Content -path $f |
ForEach-Object {
    $line = $_

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $line.Length; $i += $limit)
    {
        $length = [Math]::Min($limit, $line.Length - $i)
        $line.SubString($i, $length)     
    
    }
} |
Set-Content $f
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  I had to put ( ) around get-content.  Basically means - finish what you are doing before going to the next step.

[int] $limit = 131

$path = get-content C:\Soarian\fix.txt
foreach ($f in $path)
{
**(**Get-Content -path $f**)** |
ForEach-Object {
$line = $_

```
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $line.Length; $i += $limit)
    {
        $length = [Math]::Min($limit, $line.Length - $i)
        $line.SubString($i, $length)   
    
    
    }
} |
Set-Content $f -Force
```

}

Comment: For reference, ```( ... )``` is called the Grouping Operator - official documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#grouping-operator--